# Incluir if na query

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de Incluir uma condição na query sql, segue.

```
$Q_horario =    "SELECT   ".
            "   H.horario As horario,   ".
            "   L.codigo As codlinha,   ".
            "   L.descricao As linha,   ".
            "   L.tipo As tipo,   ".
            "   IF (H.sentido='I',L.saida,L.chegada) As saida,   ".
            "   IF (H.sentido='I',L.chegada,L.saida) As chegada,   ".
            "   T. valor As tarifa   ".
            "FROM tarifas T  ". 
            "   INNER JOIN linhas L ON L.codigo = T.linha  ". 
            "   INNER JOIN horarios H ON H.linha = L.codigo  ". 
            if ($entra == 3){
            "INNER JOIN cidade C on C.origem = T.origem AND C.destino = T.destino ".
                                       "AND C.entra = 'N' ".
                                       "AND C.diasemana = 'DOM'".
                                       "AND C.horario = H.horario".
            }
            "WHERE T.origem = $origem ".  
            "   AND T.destino= $destino   ".
            "   AND H.sentido = '$sentido'".
            "   AND ((MID(H.frequencia, '$dia', 1) = 'S') AND (MID(H.frequencia1002, '$dia', 1) = 'S')) ".
            "ORDER BY T.linha, H.horario ";
```

Teria alguma forma de incluir esse if?, seira tipo um filtro;

pois dessa forma da erro de syntax

Comment: Outra opção é usar o [`CASE WHEN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Talvez você tenha que estudar um pouco mais sobre lógica de programação. A solução parece ser bem simples, basta encerrar a concatenação na primeira linha, antes do `if`. Em seguida você prossegue com ela depois dele. E fazer a concatenação dentro do if também, assim:

```
$Q_horario =    "SELECT   ".
        "   H.horario As horario,   ".
        "   L.codigo As codlinha,   ".
        "   L.descricao As linha,   ".
        "   L.tipo As tipo,   ".
        "   IF (H.sentido='I',L.saida,L.chegada) As saida,   ".
        "   IF (H.sentido='I',L.chegada,L.saida) As chegada,   ".
        "   T. valor As tarifa   ".
        "FROM tarifas T  ". 
        "   INNER JOIN linhas L ON L.codigo = T.linha  ". 
        "   INNER JOIN horarios H ON H.linha = L.codigo  "; // encerra a concatenação...

         // faz o "IF"
        if ($entra == 3){
        $Q_horario = $Q_horario . "INNER JOIN cidade C on C.origem = T.origem AND C.destino = T.destino ".
                                   "AND C.entra = 'N' ".
                                   "AND C.diasemana = 'DOM'".
                                   "AND C.horario = H.horario";// encerra a concatenação do "if"
        }// encerra o "if"

        // faz o resto da concatenação:
        $Q_horario = $Q_horario . "WHERE T.origem = $origem ".  
        "   AND T.destino= $destino   ".
        "   AND H.sentido = '$sentido'".
        "   AND ((MID(H.frequencia, '$dia', 1) = 'S') AND (MID(H.frequencia1002, '$dia', 1) = 'S')) ".
        "ORDER BY T.linha, H.horario ";
```

Para concatenar você pode utilizar tanto `$variavel = $variavel . "outra coisa";` quanto `$variavel .= "outra coisa";`.

Comment: `$Q_horario = $Q_horario . "` pode ser trocado por `$Q_horario .= "`

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam editei e inseri essa informação. Geralmente tento simplificar o código para deixá-lo "entendível" pro AP, afinal é uma dúvida simples, talvez ele não saberia o que é `.=`. Mas desse jeito ele fica mais limpo e funciona da mesma maneira. :)

Comment: Não está concatenando, ele faz o select mesmo com a condição.

Comment: @AriMelo, não entendi muito bem... Ele vai executar o `SELECT` de qualquer maneira mesmo, a condição é apenas para o `INNER JOIN` dentro do `if`. Ocorre algum erro?

Comment: @bio então, o select entra sim, mais ele não está executando o if, não ocorre erro, apenas pula o if. o select com if e sem if está testado e funciona 100%